# Using PDO in other classes very simply

Tags: php, pdo

I have read a few tutorials and discussions regarding the above issue but before using one of those I'm wondering whether my solution is acceptable. The thing is I don't want to extend my Db class to all my classes where I run queries (feels weird), as per one of the suggestions, I'm also not sure if constructors or self instances are essential. I'm not against them maybe I just spent too much time in the procedural universe.

So, I have a classic Db class with the usual parameters. I want to run queries inside other classes so I thought I'd simply pass PDO as a parameter. Can I just use it like this, does this have any kickbacks?

```
<?php

    include 'db.php'; // usual stuff, returns PDO

    $obj = new Db;
    $obj->connect();

    class User { // in a separate file, normally

        public function getUser($obj) {
            $res=$obj->connect()->query("SELECT * FROM users");
            $row=$res->fetch();
            print_r($row);
        }
    }

    $u=new User;
    $u->getUser($obj);

?>
```

Comment: I suggest creating a base Controller class that has access to the essential classes you'll most likely use per class. All of your classes extends this one to get access to the common vars - but this is my preference ...

Comment: Are you sure about this? You'd have to pass the DB class everywhere. Have a look at service containers to avoid instantiating each and every repository by hand

Comment: Well I'm of course not sure about anything. But I'll look into these thanks guys.

Answer (score 3):

Make a User service/repository class, that handles all the stuff you'd like to do with your user. Pass the DB into that instead. Example interface:

```
interface UserServiceInterface
{
    public function __construct(Db $db);
    public function createUserFromArray(array $data) : User;
    public function findUser(int $id) : User;
    public function deleteUser(int $id) : bool;
    //etc, toArray, whatever else you might need
}
```

Leave your User as a plain old PHP object (POPO) with getters and setters for the fields.

Comment: this is also not a bad idea ^^

Comment: ThisGuyHasThumbs, I think it's nicer than sticking it in the controller, i like my controllers just calling a service class and passing parameters to it, returning output and handling exceptions. no business logic! Also means you can move it to another framework easily

Comment: true true, though I suppose that last segment may be framework specific (e.g. Symfony has that base controller class with access to certain vars etc.) but yeah the logic is sound

Comment: It gets even simpler when the framework in question uses PSR-7 requests and responses. Then you can even make generic controller code!

Comment: This looks good thanks. But after digging the internet for hours I realized I'm not here yet.